# SerialPort->Write Gets Stuck randomly?

Tags: serial-port, c++-cli

I have to communicate with a device via serial communication.
As I'm using C++/CLI , I use the function "SerialPort.Write"
Everything works fine and then randomly the program is stuck.Only way to get it back is by removing the USB cable.
I have set the timeout to 500ms.

Comment: Timeouts are implemented by the device driver.  The worst kind of device drivers are certainly found in USB drivers that emulate a serial port.  Throw it away, buy another one.  Spend more than 10 bucks.  And never disconnect the cable when the port is opened, always use "Safely remove hardware".

Comment: But I cannot buy another ... the hardware has a different kind of male connector at the other end....  in that case would it be helpful if we use serial to usb converter and than connect it to this cable